# using form buttons for spamproof email-addresses

Tags: forms, spam-prevention, web-crawler

I have been looking at some methods for spamproof email methods [here](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/). I'd like to propose a more simple approach: Since I need a couple of different email addresses I considered just using a selectbox with JS or serverside redirect, as per examples [on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687976/php-page-redirect-dependant-on-select-box-choice). 
Because google doesn't spider forms (dixit Matt Cutts), and spam-harvester script don't either (I think????) this would make sense to do.

I would love to be able to do this without using a script. So why not use one form per email?

```
<form action="mailto:test@domain.tld" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="test@domain.tld"/>
</form>
```

It seems the button text can be copied but not pasted, so that's a disadvantage.

Is this approach any good? or any other recommendations?

Comment: Yes do that!!! For like all you questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because:

1. The email address is still in the page, and thus easily harvestable
2. [mailto: URIs as form actions often fail](http://www.isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)

The reason server side form handlers stop email addresses being harvested is because the email address is not exposed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

A robot uses the text of the page to get the email. It does not care if that text is in a button or within the body so using a button will not help.

Outside of using javascript, the only solution I know of would be written text, an image or Flash.

Create an image with your email or write out the email like: "test at domain dot tld"

Flash could provide you with a more secure (but not 100%) way of allowing people to click on an email but would not work on iPhone browsers and those that do not have the plug-in.

Another way is to use a simple captcha to before displaying the email in the PHP code.

Email: (1+2 = ?) then test@domain.tld